# multiple routes file rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code

application.rb

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/config/routes)
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'summary#index'

  extend General
end
```

/config/routes/general.rb

```
module General
  def self.extended(router)
    router.instance_exec do

      # devise routes
      devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: 'users/sessions' }
    end
  end
end
```

I get `uninitialized constant General` when loading the app.

I''m using Ruby 2.2.6 and Rails 5.0.2

Answer (score 0):

in rails 6, you can use `draw(:general)`, which will look for route definition in config/routes/general.rb

You can emulate this with an initializer:

```
module RoutesSubfolder
  # Extension to Rails routes mapper to provide the ability to draw routes
  # present in a subfolder
  #
  # Another solution would be to add the files to `config.paths['config/routes']`
  # but this solution guarantees the routes order
  #
  # Example: <config/routes.rb>
  #
  #   Rails.application.routes.draw do
  #     # this will eval the file config/routes/api.rb
  #     draw :api
  #
  # Example:
  #   draw :'api/whatever' # loads config/routes/api/whatever.rb
  #
  def draw(name)
    path = Rails.root.join('config', 'routes', "#{name}.rb")

    unless File.exist?(path)
      raise StandardError, "Unable to draw routes from non-existing file #{path}"
    end

    instance_eval(File.read(path), path.to_s, 1)
  end
end

ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper.prepend(RoutesSubfolder)
```

The only difference with what you proposed is that:

- you don't need to change the autoload_path
- in general.rb, you directly declare your routes the same way you'd do in config/routes.rb inside the `Rails.application.routes.draw do` block

Comment: Hm, I'm still running into errors, just to check where do I place the draw method? Also I am using rails 5

Comment: The code ports the `draw` method of rails6 to rails 3, 4, and 5. Add the code in an initializer, then where you would usually call `resources` for example, call `draw :general`